# Statistical Significance Three-sided Die

Tags: statistics

I am working with a process that, on each iteration, produces either a value of -1, 0, or 1. So for all intents and purposes, we can assume I am talking about a three sided die.

I would like to devise a test that tells me whether the die is loaded or not. Specifically, I would like to know:

(a) how many iterations do I need in order to conclude whether it is loaded or not?
(b) given that I have enough iterations, is it loaded toward -1, 0, or 1?

Comment: Maybe the idea of [p-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) will be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a [Chi-squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test):

1. Choose $N\geq15$ (I'd suggest 30 to be safe) to ensure that you have enough expected samples per "bin": $X=1,X=0,X=-1$
2. Observe $N$ die rolls, and record the number of times it came up $1,0,-1$, record the totals in the associated bins.
3. Calculate the *chi-squared statistic*:

[image]

Here: $n=3$, $E_i=\frac{N}{3}$ and $O_i$ is the number you actually observed of each outcome.

4. $\chi^2$ will have a $\chi^2_1$ distribution, since you have three bins, but need the sum of the observations $N$ and the sum of the $p_i$ to equal 1. So you lose 2 degrees of freedom.

Now just choose your acceptable (one sided, upper tailed) probability of incorrectly rejecting a fair die $\alpha$, and look up the associated $1-\alpha$ percentile of the chi-squared distribution with one degree of freedom.